# What quotes or function should I use to wrap this PHP string?

Tags: php, string, variables

I have a CMS which builds content to a static page. You just place some made up "tags" in the HTML source and the CMS converts them with the database value.

```
$faqContent = "<cms:html_body>";
$faqContent = '<cms:html_body>';
```

The problem is, some of the fields have apostrophes (for grammar), some of the fields have double quotes (as some include hyper links).

So if I wrap $faqContent in single or double quotes, it will break at least once depending on what field it is outputting.

I'm confused now.. what shall I do? I don't want to convert to ASCII codes as the hyperlinks will output as text, not HTML.

Comment: Consider parsing the tags apostrphoes or double quotes , something like `htmlspecialchars` maybe. Otherwise it seems like a bad practice.

Comment: You can escape your quotes

Comment: You can use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) format

Answer (score 1):

For simple bits of code you have to use [regular PHP strings.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

However, **you have to avoid defining large amounts of structured text as PHP strings**.
Load them from a file instead or use some sort of a templating system